# cannot reshape array of size 12212 into shape (400,400,180)

Tags: python, opencv

I wanted to convert my images from .zraw to .png and I used this code

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
sample='b001'
path='C:/Users/21650/Desktop/base_image/'+sample+'/'
file= path +'gt_noclip.zraw'
ptr = open(file,'rb')
data = np.fromfile(ptr,dtype=np.float32)
#read the values of dim_1, dim_2 and dim_3 from image.mhd
dim_1=400
dim_2=400
dim_3=180
img=data.reshape(dim_2,dim_1,dim_3)
#plt.figure()
#plt.axis('off')
#plt.gray()
for ctr in range(dim_1):
    save_file=path +'/image_cor/'+'mask_'+sample+'_'+str(ctr)+'.png'
```

but a value error appeared

> img=data.reshape(dim_2,dim_1,dim_3)
>
> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12212 into shape
> (400,400,180)

could any one help me

Comment: A `.zraw` file has compressed data, and `numpy.fromfile` will not decompress it. So the array of size 12212 is the compressed data. Try using SimpleITK.

Comment: You might also need the associated `.mhd` files (or some other paired file). The other file should have metadata about the `.zraw` file, including information like data type and size.